# Function for calculating tangents in a cubic Bézier curve

Tags: derivative, cubic-bezier

How do you calculate the in-tangents and out-tangents of a cubic Bézier curve, knowing the following: start control point (x1, y1), end control point (x2, y2) and end point (x, y)?